# I'm thinking of blocking access to every part of my site other than these (SSH/HTTP). Is this a good idea?

Tags: apache, security, ubuntu, ssh, ftp

I think this should be standard for everybody to do anyway, but maybe I'm missing something.

I want to block access to my site through every port/method/protocol except a select few methods:

- This includes blocking use of the IP address rather than the domain name. So visits to 123.55.123.66 and ssh://123.55.123.66 will always fail.
- Also, blocking all FTP access

These only will be allowed:

(1) http://domain.com

(2) https://domain.com

(3) ssh://ssh-access.domain.com

So SSH is only available at this subdomain, so people can't hit SSH from the IP or the same domain that is publicly available.

Also, http://ssh-access.domain.com would fail.

No access to FTP, Telnet anything.

Is this a good idea?

Because I can't even think of all the different ports/protcols available, I think it's best to block all except the above listed (rather than block all FTP, SSH etc.).

Also, if anyone has any pointers as to how I would code this, that would be great. I'm guessing it's best to do it in Apache (or Ubuntu).

Comment: There is a sister site of Stack Overflow where your question would be more on topic. Please check [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com). If you intend to do the blocking via code, though, then it is on topic here, but we'll ask you to include your attempted solutions.

Comment: This is not standard because it's no use. Use firewalling, VPNs and key authentication for building a truly secure setup. This gives an _illusion_ of security, which is even worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "visit" `ssh://123.55.123.66` in the proper sense (i.e. with a web browser) and, although some file browsers offer this extension, Apache is not involved in the connection (instead, the SSH daemon is). Moreover, SSH daemon has no notion of "(sub)domain".

That said, you can configure SSH daemon to listen only on the "remote access" IP address (*bind* it to that address).

For the website, you can adapt the appropriate Mod-Security rules to deny access to people/bots trying to access the website by IP address, rather than by web address.